# extract a substring as a new field in grok

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm new no ELK stack and I have a log file and I need to create a new field as service to identify from which service the log is generated using a substring in the log. A sample logline is given below. I need a grok expression to filter the `****SyncLeaveRecord started*****` string as a new field.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-08-08 00:44:00,009]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = ****SyncLeaveRecord started***** {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't say if `****SyncLeaveRecord started*****` always has this value, I've based the grok pattern on the elements around it, supposing those don't change.

```
grok {
  match => {message => 
    "STATUS = %{DATA:newField} \{"
  }
}
```

Which, given the sample logline, creates a new field called `newField`, containing `****SyncLeaveRecord·started*****`.